# mojolicious app conrollers doesn t render the template they should render

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I will explain my issue with the code:

first my app (ls -R):
/Kantine
Controllers  kantine.conf  kantine.pl  Kantine.pm templates

Kantine/Controllers:
Restaurant.pm  Sandwich.pm

Kantine/templates:
cantine.html.ep

I launch it under hypnotoad with the command "hypnotoad kantine.pl".
Everything is fine

Kantine/kantine.pm :

```
package Kantine;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious';

sub startup
{
    my $self = shift;
    my $config = $self->plugin('Config');

    my $r = $self->routes;
    $r->get('/restaurant')->to('restaurant#loadData');
    $r->get('/sandwich')->to('sandwich#loadData');
    $r->get('/test')->to(template => 'cantine');
}

1;
```

Kantine/Controllers/Restaurant :

package Controllers::Restaurant;

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub loadData
{
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render('cantine');
}

1;
```

"curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/test" works fine (got a blank page) but "curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/restaurant" doesn't (got page not found). And I don't unerstand why! If you see what is wrong..

Thx!

Comment: Spelling error? You have `loadData` in one place and `loadDate` in the other (Thank you for cutting and pasting your real code).

Comment: Fix it but seems to be there is something more! I will edit it in the post too thx! I add a log file and it s telling me that "Controller "Kantine::Restaurant" does not exist", I will try to see why :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that all the places you have used `Controllers` should instead be `Controller` (singular). The `/test` route works because Mojolicious can find the template in `templates`, however it doesn't look in `Controllers` so it can't find `Controllers::Restaurant`.

Comment: Yeah my paths were wrong, I doesn't have access to the file anymore so I can't be sure of it but you must be close.